# Disable autofocus and selection on TextField on swiftui macos app open

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

On app open autofocus and all content selection happen for TextField.
How to disable this behaviour?

MacOS Monterey 12.1
Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100)

[image: autofocused field]

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FocusApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var editTitle: String = "test"
    var body: some View {
        TextField("add title ...", text: $editTitle)
            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but perhaps it depends on OS version -- can you add that info to your post?

Comment: @jnpdx
MacOS Monterey 12.1
Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100)

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you enable "keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" in the keyboard settings of your Mac.

[image]